# RESTful API Design based on the RBAC model

Tags: rest, security, jwt, roles, rbac

The problem to face lies in the design of a RESTful API that can manage requests from multiple roles in an RBAC-based solution.

Currently we have different resources that can be accessed from different users, which can have one or more roles grouped according to their privileges.

The API we're trying to define must be as clear as possible to the client but without the overhead of adding additional metadata to the URL that could damage and even conflict with the REST practices and definitions. Therefore, we must avoid at all costs include information about the roles inside the URL. The plan is to use JWT tokens that carry in their payloads the info needed to know which permissions has the user making the request.

Having raised our current situation, let's provide an example and state the problem to solve:

Suppose we have * financiers * and * providers * as users with some roles who both want to access ** attentions ** (our resource). Should we add before the resource ** attentions ** information about the * user * whose trying to access the resource?

The endpoints in that case should be defined (as an example) as:

```
https://example.com/api/v1/financiers/:id/attentions
https://example.com/api/v1/providers/:id/attentions
```

This way we're attempting to inform the respective controllers that we want the ** attentions ** for that specific role / user which are, in some way, a sub-resource of them.

On the other hand, we could simply implement a much simpler endpoint as follows:

```
https://example.com/api/v1/attentions
```

The logic about which attentions return from the database should be now implemented in an unique method that must handle this two roles (and potentially new ones that could come up in the following features). All the information needed must be obtained from the payload from the token, exposing a much more generic API and freeing the web client from the responsibility of which endpoint call depending on the role.

I want to highlight that the attentions are managed in a Microservices Architecture and, hence, the logic to retrieve them is gathered in a single service. The cost of the API Gateway to route the two (and potentially more) of the endpoints from the first solution is a variable not to discard in our specific situation.

Having exposed our current situation:

- Which we'll be the best approach to handle this issue?
- Is there another alternative not contemplated that could ease the role management and provide a clean API to expose to the client?
- In the second solution, is correct to return only the attentions accessible to that specific user based on the roles that it has? Isn't it   counterintuitive to access an endpoint and only get some of the resources from that collection (and not all) based on its role?

I hope that someone could clarify the approach we're taking as there are little and none literature that I've found regarding this issue.

Answer (score -1):

There there are multiple solutions for such kind of filtration, and developer have to select one depending on given situation.

As per my experience I can list following.

### Structure

When data can't be accessed directly and developer has to use a relation (i.e a table JOIN). In that case URL have to include both the main and sub entities. Before going with this approach a good check is to ask, if the same URL can be used with POST ?

#### Example

If we have to fetch list of roles assigned to a specific user or want to assign additional roles then we can use

```
GET users/:uid/roles
POST users/:uid/roles
```

### Security

With Multi-tenant systems where each user can have his/her private resources, i.e other users are prohibited from accessing those resources. Developer should save tenancy information and to filter the resources according to current authentication, without bothering client or requiring any additional info in URL

#### Example

Phone album of the user

```
GET photos
POST photos
```

### Search

If it is not security or structure related but client still want to filter the result set depending on his scenario. then developer should use query-string for the filtration.

#### Example

Client have to fetch messages from his/her inbox or outbox or want messages which are not yet read. or he/she want to search his/her inbox

```
GET messages?folder=inbox
GET messages?folder=inbox&status=unread
GET messages?search=nasir
```

Comment: As I see, in neither of the three approaches there's a need to know which roles does the user has. Everything happens behind the scenes in the backend and the client only has to take care of calling a generic endpoint that will return the resources that have asked for. The third soluction which implies filtering the response would be among the resources that the backend has already decided to return to the user, so the user doesn't even know that there are other similar resources in the same collection that doesn't have access to. Should we go with the second approach that I proposed then?

Comment: Yes! you got it, you have to go for **security** and regarding list of roles, It can be encoded in jwt or you can fetch it from database using provided user authentication.